# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) Xcode 10.2.1

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, configuration, unnotificationserviceextension

I know this question has been asked a lot of times and there are many probable answer, but none of them helped me to get over my problem.
Here some possible solution's which I am trying out.
[Solution1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40365354/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-duplicate-symbol-tmrbbp) [Solution2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50509245/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-firebase) and many suggested solutions on the site.

I am also using Notification service & Notification Content Extension in my project.Also I am using firebase for push notifications.
From the time since I have integrated .xcconfig files to manage staging and production configuarations using **[This](https://medium.com/@maanrashpindersingh/complete-tutorial-to-organise-ios-xcode-project-staging-development-and-release-states-with-f56bc3f8ca75)** tutorial all the problems have started.

```
Showing Recent Messages

Ld /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.appex/NotificationContent normal x86_64
 cd /Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code
 export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=12.2
 export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker /usr/lib/swift -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator12.2.sdk -L/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/FreshchatSDK/FreshchatSDK -L/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/FreshchatSDK -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AMPopTip -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSCore -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSS3 -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AlamofireSwiftyJSON -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Arcane -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/BSErrorMessageView -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Cosmos -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CreditCardValidator -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/DynamicBlurView -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FeedKit -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDynamicLinks -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IQKeyboardManagerSwift -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ImageSlideshow -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JVFloatLabeledTextField -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/KVNProgress -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MarqueeLabel -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Moya -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NKVPhonePicker -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpalImagePicker -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/PopupDialog -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RadioButton -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ReachabilitySwift -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Result -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBTickerView -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SVProgressHUD -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Shimmer -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftValidator -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftyJSON -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UPCarouselFlowLayout -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ViewPager-Swift -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMGaugeView -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libwebp -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios -F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/AppsFlyerFramework -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/FBSDKMarketingKit -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/vipulthaware/HealthDekho/Projects/B2C/App/Code/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -filelist /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Intermediates.noindex/B2C.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NotificationContent.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../../Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=12.2 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Intermediates.noindex/B2C.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NotificationContent_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fapplication-extension -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Intermediates.noindex/B2C.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NotificationContent.swiftmodule -ObjC -lFDFreshchatSDK -lc++ -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AMPopTip -framework AVFoundation -framework AWSCore -framework AWSS3 -framework Accelerate -framework AdSupport -framework Alamofire -framework AlamofireSwiftyJSON -framework AppsFlyerLib -framework Arcane -framework AssetsLibrary -framework AudioToolbox -framework BSErrorMessageView -framework Bolts -framework CFNetwork -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreTelephony -framework Cosmos -framework Crashlytics -framework CreditCardValidator -framework DynamicBlurView -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKMarketingKit -framework FIRAnalyticsConnector -framework Fabric -framework FeedKit -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseDynamicLinks -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseMessaging -framework Foundation -framework GLKit -framework GoogleAppMeasurement -framework GoogleUtilities -framework IQKeyboardManagerSwift -framework ImageIO -framework ImageSlideshow -framework JVFloatLabeledTextField -framework KVNProgress -framework Lottie -framework MarqueeLabel -framework MessageUI -framework Moya -framework NKVPhonePicker -framework OpalImagePicker -framework Photos -framework PopupDialog -framework Protobuf -framework QuartzCore -framework RadioButton -framework ReachabilitySwift -framework Result -framework SBTickerView -framework SDWebImage -framework SVProgressHUD -framework Security -framework Shimmer -framework StoreKit -framework SwiftValidator -framework SwiftyJSON -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -framework UPCarouselFlowLayout -framework ViewPager_Swift -framework WMGaugeView -framework iAd -framework libwebp -framework nanopb -weak_framework Accounts -weak_framework AudioToolbox -weak_framework CoreGraphics -weak_framework CoreLocation -weak_framework Foundation -weak_framework QuartzCore -weak_framework Security -weak_framework Social -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework WebKit -e _NSExtensionMain -Xlinker -sectcreate -Xlinker __TEXT -Xlinker __entitlements -Xlinker /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Intermediates.noindex/B2C.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.build/NotificationContent.appex-Simulated.xcent -framework UserNotificationsUI -framework UserNotifications -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Intermediates.noindex/B2C.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/NotificationContent_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/NotificationContent.appex/NotificationContent

ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSS3'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Bolts'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBSDKCoreKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FeedKit'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseCore'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseDynamicLinks'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FirebaseMessaging'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/GoogleUtilities'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JVFloatLabeledTextField'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Moya'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/OpalImagePicker'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Protobuf'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RadioButton'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SBTickerView'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SDWebImage'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SVProgressHUD'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/UPCarouselFlowLayout'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/ViewPager-Swift'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/WMGaugeView'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libwebp'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/lottie-ios'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vipulthaware/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/B2C-bqqgcxfxnnaoajdltkdbsssioail/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/nanopb'
ld: framework not found AMPopTip
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please Suggest what is the possible solution or have I done any thing wrong,
please let me know if any extra explanation or detail is required my side

Comment: We'll there's your problem -->  'ld: framework not found AMPopTip'. This doesn't appear to have anything to do with Firebase. Also, seems you may have moved a referenced file so see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option) answer.

Comment: @Jay I did things suggested for Notification Service & Notification content extension
But started getting same error for other frameworks
please suggest

Comment: That's a two year old article which may contain outdated info. Also, as I mentioned, if you moved a file it will cause that error. The only option is to start removing frameworks and commenting out code until the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Follow these steps to find a solution**.

From the logs I have posted above one thing is clear that the problem in my case was with ***Notification Content* & *Notification Service* Extension targets**

So following [This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option#answer-18618187) based on **-L** or **-R** flag you are getting in the logs,
Delete the paths added for **Library Search Path** or **Framework Search Paths** as may be required.
*For my case I had to do this for **Notification Service & Notification Content Extension** targets*

This may cause more error where you might start getting errors for other framework or search path for same target (**which was the case with me**),
If such thing happen for any Target then try to delete the **Other Linker Flags** for the targets you are getting the error.

In my case deleting the **Library Search Path** & **Framework Search Paths** as well as **Other Linker Flags** Did the trick for me.